# Searching text in binary data

Tags: c, performance

I've a binary data which contains a text. The text is known. What could be a fast method to search for that text:

As an eg.

```
This is text 1---
!@##$%%#^%&!%^$! <= Assume this line is 3 MB of binary data
Now, This is text 2 ---
!@##$%%#^%&!%^$! <= Assume this line is 2.5 MB of binary data
This is text 3 ---
```

How can I search for text `This is text 2`.

Currently I'm doing like:

```
size_t count = 0;
size_t s_len = strlen("This is text 2");

//Assume data_len is length of the data from which text is to be found and data is pointer (char*) to the start of it.
for(; count < data_len; ++count)
{
    if(!memcmp("This is text 2", data + count, s_len)
    {
         printf("%s\n", "Hurray found you...");
    }
}
```

- Is there any other way, more efficient way to do this
- Will replacing `++count logic` with `memchr('T') logic` help <= Please ignore if this statement is not clear
- what should be the average case big-O comlexity of memchr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing in standard C to help you, but there is a GNU extension [`memmem()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memmem.3.html) that does this:

```
#define TEXT2 "This is text 2"

char *pos = memmem(data, data_len, TEXT2, sizeof(TEXT2));

if (pos != NULL)
    /* Found it. */
```

If you need to be portable to systems that don't have this, you could take the `glibc` implementation of `memmem()` and incorporate it into your program.

Comment: That is something I'm looking for. Well, I'll check it once. How safe is it to use memmem. As of now I need support for FreeBSD only. And is it fine to assume memmem will have same/similar algo/complexity as of strstr!!

Comment: @Mayank: It appears that FreeBSD has supplied this function since FreeBSD 6.0.  It *should* use a non-naive algorithm, but this is a quality-of-implementation issue.

Comment: That's alright. By the time there would be a question of performance improvement in my software, FreeBSD must have already done that with memmem :-)

Comment: Shouldn't we use "sizeof(TEXT2) - 1" since sizeof(TEXT2) return the string length + 1 (the \0)?

Comment: @Guid: That depends on whether the binary is expected to contain the null-terminated string or not.  As written it searches for the null terminator, yes.

Answer (score 4):

There are algorithms for doing exactly this with better complexity than repeated `memcmp` (which is implemented the obvious way and has the obvious complexity for near matches).

Famous algorithms are [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). These are only two examples. The general category in which these fall is "string matching".

Comment: Yeah, actually KMP is the last resort. I was looking for something which `libc.so` can provide :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is about C programming language, but have you tried to use *strings* unix tool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix) with *grep*?

```
$ strings datafile | grep "your text"
```

EDIT:

If you want to use C, I suggest to do this simple optimization:

```
size_t count = 0;
size_t s_len = strlen("This is text 2");

for(; count < data_len; ++count)
{
    if (!isprint(data[count])) continue;

    if(!memcmp("This is text 2", data + count, s_len)
    {
     printf("%s\n", "Hurray found you...");
    }
}
```

If you want a better performance, I suggest you to search and use a string matching algorithm.

Comment: Actually I need the index of start of `Now, This is text 2` and finish of `This is text 1---` so that I can extract the binary content out of the example data and save it as a file :). This usually is seen in a multipart/form-data